# Different type of padding in image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, zero-padding, finite-differences

I want to implement a gradient operator on an image in Matlab. Should I have to pad the image before its implementation? How do I decide which padding to use e.g. whether to use zero-padding or Symmetric padding? How are they differ from each other? I am new to this field of image processing, Can you provide some references to learn this stuff?

Comment: It depends on the context you want to apply it. Is it to solve some optimization problem or just for visualization or farther processing?

Comment: I use it in optimization, for the implementation of total variation (T.V.). Now, it solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients enhances differences. Hence, highly non-smooth padding (like zero-padding) yields higher gradients, as they don't ensure continuity. Symmetric extensions preserve continuity, and anti-symmetric ones are likely to better preserve derivatives. There is a lot of literature on that, for instance in the filter bank domain. Suppose that the edge sample is $x[0]$, you can have whole-sample anti-symmetry or half-sample anti-symmetry:

- $x[-1] = -x[1]+2x[0] $
- $x[-1] = x[0] $ and $x[-2] = -x[1]+2x[0] $

This is illustrated in the picture, from the first paper mentioned below. One can find whole-sample (WS) and half-sample (HS) symmetries and anti-symmetries. A lot of image processing operators combine symmetry or anti-symmetry, so those can be useful.

[image: Lifted linear phase filter banks and the polyphase-with-advance representation [JPEG 2000 image coding applications]

A couple of pointers:

- [Lifted linear phase filter banks and the polyphase-with-advance representation (JPEG 2000 image coding applications)](https://doi.org/10.1109/DSPWS.2004.1437905)
- [Classification of Nonexpansive Symmetric Extension Transforms for Multirate Filter Banks](https://core.ac.uk/reader/82070944)
- [Unitary FIR filter banks and symmetry](https://doi.org/10.1109/82.329740)

> Recently, unitary FIR filter banks with linear-phase have been
> completely parameterized by exploiting the eigenstructure of the
> exchange matrix. This correspondence gives new characterizations of
> polyphase matrices of filter banks with various types of symmetry on
> the filters. Using matrix extensions of the well-known hyperbolic and
> orthogonal lattices, we give a alternative proof for the
> parameterization of linear-phase unitary filter banks. A complete
> parameterization of FIR unitary filter banks with each of the
> different types of symmetries considered (not just linear-phase) is
> also given. These results can also be used to generate non-unitary
> filter banks with symmetries, though no completeness results can be
> obtained. In some cases implicit, and in others explicit
> parameterization of wavelet tight frames associated with these filter
> banks are also given. This paper only considers filter banks with an
> even number of channels. A similar theory can be developed if the
> number of channels is an odd integer.

Aside, there are many other possible extensions, using constant continuation (or pixel replication), or higher-order (*eg* linear, polynomial) extrapolations:

- [Image padding, REFLECTION padding](https://kegui.medium.com/image-padding-reflection-padding-d3dee4dc2f63)

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight of the answer. Can you please share some links for that.